# ActiveRecord Join, Group By, Sum, Having

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given the following classes

```
class Invoice
    has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem
    belongs_to :invoice
end
```

How can I find invoices whose line_item sums doesn't match the total stored in the invoice.  The closest guess I can come up with is:

```
Invoice.joins(:line_items)
       .group_by(:invoice_id)
       .select('invoice_id, sum(line_items.amount) as line_item_total')
       .having('line_item_total <> invoice.total')
```

I would like for this to create and run a single sql statement.  But ActiveRecord seems to be first trying to select everything.  And then I get a 'ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)'

Please advise on correct syntax and method to execute a single SQL query.

Comment: This looks correct. What are you looking for?

Comment: I would like for this to create and run a single sql statement. But ActiveRecord seems to be first trying to select everything. And then I get a 'ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)'

Comment: rrrr ... group! not group_by